# Airmong-ng start wlan0 comment not found

Tags: command-line

I updated `aptitude`,  installed `aircrack-ng`, but still `airmon-ng` command in not working...

Comment: Run it through the terminal and paste the output as part of your answer

Comment: Devrobot - I can't understand...  please can you explain.

Comment: Run `airmon-ng` through the command line - just type `airmon-ng`

Comment: Devrobot - I did,  but it's showing command not found..

Comment: Install it using `sudo aptitude install aircrack-ng` or `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` and run it by `sudo airmon-ng`

Comment: Ron - i installed by the comment -> sudo aptitude update <- update over,  then I tried ->airmon-ng start wlan0<-   but no use.

Comment: Ron - thank you,   -> sudo airmon-ng <- ,   works...

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the `airmon-ng` command requires root priveleges, which can be gained through `sudo`:

```
sudo airmon-ng
```